remove module from loading permanently
Ubuntu 22.
I have my own test module called mypcidriver.ko and two moschip semiconductor technology ltd pci 9835 multi-i/o controller.
sudo find /sys | grep drivers.*03:0 gives me /sys/bus/pci/drivers/serial/0000:03:00.0 and /sys/bus/pci/drivers/serial/0000:03:02.0 so I unbinded serial and binded mypcidriver each time but now I need it to load automatically with the system.
I put mypcidriver.ko to /lib/modules/5.15.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/my, did depmod -a
I've added line "mypcidriver" to /etc/modules
I've added lines blacklist serial and blacklist parport_serial to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
did update-initramfs –u
and after reboot i can see mypcidriver by lsmod but sudo find /sys | grep drivers.*03:0 gives me /sys/bus/pci/drivers/serial/0000:03:00.0 and /sys/bus/pci/drivers/serial/0000:03:02.0 like it was before and lspci -v gives  Kernel driver in use: serial and Kernel modules: parport_serial, mypcidriver
my googling gives me only pages where people forget to do smth that i've done and after they fixed it they get the result but i'm not. so what else i should do to make my module load with the system and work with my devices automatically?
